# is there a R function (or sequence of steps) to grouping and summarise (count) a dataframe like this (with some repeated values in the rows)

Tags: r, count, grouping, unique, summarize

I have a df like that

```
df = data.frame (user = c('u1', 'u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2'),
                 entity = c('e1','e2','e3','e3','e4'),
                 area = c('a1','a1','a2','a2','a1'),
                 sex=c('M','M','M','F','F'))
```

and i need to obtain a df like that

```
df2<- data.frame (area = c('a1', 'a2'),
                  male = c(1,1),
                  female = c(1,1),
                  total=c(2,2))
```

Count the number of women and men by area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df = data.frame (user = c('u1', 'u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2'),
                 entity = c('e1','e2','e3','e3','e4'),
                 area = c('a1','a1','a2','a2','a1'),
                 sex=c('M','M','M','F','F'))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  distinct(user, area, sex) %>%
  mutate(sex = ifelse(sex == "M", "male", "female")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = area,
    names_from = sex,
    values_from = sex,
    values_fill = 0,
    values_fn = length
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(across(male:female)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   area   male female Total
#>   <chr> <int>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 a1        1      1     2
#> 2 a2        1      1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your help, I was trying with this.
df%>%group_by(area,sex) %>% 
  summarise (count =n()) %>% 
  spread(key= sex,value=count)

but it's not what i expected , so thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I am still not quite sure. I am using the idea of Yuriy Saraykin with `distinct` (credits to him +1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  distinct(user, area, sex) %>%
  group_by(area, sex) %>% 
  summarise(value =n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = sex,
    values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(F, M)) %>% 
  rename(female=F, male=M)
```

```
area  female  male total
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1 a1         1     1     2
2 a2         1     1     2
```

**First answer: Not correct!**
One way could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(area, sex) %>% 
  summarise(value =n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = sex,
    values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  mutate(total = F+M) %>% 
  rename(female=F, male=M)
```

```
 area  female  male total
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1 a1         1     2     3
2 a2         1     1     2
```